# MySQL get Primary Key after Insert Statment

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, mysqli

I need to use the following insert statement, and the primary key field is auto increment. I need to return the new primary key value after the insert. Preferably using one statement to do the insert and return primary key value.

```
$query = $database->connection->prepare("INSERT INTO accounts (created, priviledge, password, token, idle) VALUE ('$created', '1', :password, '$token_encrypt', '$idle')");    
$query->bindParam(":password", $password_hash);    
$query->execute();
```

Comment: `$database->connection->lastInsertId()` assuming you use PDO

Comment: Works great, will this return the value from the existing $query only? In other words, what if another instance of the script is running, is there any chance it would return the incorrect value from the other instance?

Comment: no. lastinsertid applies only to **YOUR** script, and **ONLY** that particular DB connection. other users running this or other code in parallel will not affect your ID, other than maybe using up other ids so THIS script's id sequence may not be sequential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you're using PDO you need to use

```
$database->connection->lastInsertId()
```

And it *guarantees* you to return the value from the current session. So answering to your question from comments - there is no chance you get the wrong value from a concurrent session.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_insert_id();` to get the ID generated in the last query.

It retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query (usually INSERT).

Answer (score 0):

assume your primary field name is id then try this code

```
SELECT max(id) FROM tableName
```

or try this

```
LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `TR_AI_mytable`;
CREATE TRIGGER `TR_AI_mytable` AFTER INSERT 
    ON `mytable` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET @mylastPK = new.PKField;
END;
$$
```