# Probable concurrency issue - how to solve?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a question regarding transaction handling through PHP. Please note I have checked the following questions but wasn't satisfied exactly.

[Get the new record primary key ID from mysql insert query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112852/get-the-new-record-primary-key-id-from-mysql-insert-query)

[MySQL get Primary Key after Insert Statment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412658/mysql-get-primary-key-after-insert-statment)

In the first question Duncan explains that there will be concurrency issue and needs to solve it through PHP. But I have no clue how to do that.

Let me first give you the database structure.

```
create table T1 (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

create table T2 (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    T1_id int not null,
    name varchar(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (T1_id) references T1(id)
)

create table T3 (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    T1_id int not null,
    name varchar(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (T1_id) references T1(id)
)
```

Now I have to insert data to these in a single shot through my PHP Webservice. So in the PHP code, I am executing these four queries in a row -

```
(Q1) insert into T1 (name) values ('ABC');
(Q2) pk = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();//pseudocode
(Q3) insert into T2 (T1_id, name) values (pk, 'XYZ');
(Q4) insert into T3 (T1_id, name) values (pk, 'MNP');
```

At the start of execution I am setting auto-commit as false and then depending on success or failure executing commit/rollback.

But won't there be any concurrency issue? Let's say T1 has got two rows before we start the concurrent test. So when Q2 gets executed for user U1, 
he/she will 3 whereas user U2 will also get 3 because no commit has been made. If that's the case how to solve it?